Can "go into" ever be used to mean "used in" or "made of"?
I have heard people say this, and finally have a written example: "The lower grade wood would go into window frames." https://thehistoricdistrict.org/viewtopic.php?t=304

I sense an elliptical making: The lower grade wood would go into [making] window frames.

What makes you think it can be used in the sense "made of" from the example you provide?

The phrasal verb go into is used in the sense of be used in quite frequently. An example found on line is

Steel production accounts for around 12% of global carbon emissions and over one tenth of global steel production by volume goes into the automotive sector.

It is not used to mean be made of.

It's used even more frequently of time, money, and effort ("Three years' work went into...", "All his money goes into...", etc). But perfectly fine with other resources and raw materials.

The nearest mention of this sense (for materials) I can find in the usual sources is << go into something ... [5]:  To be added to something: • In this cake recipe, the sugar goes into the batter before the flour. >> [ American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs.] But this is subtly different; OP's usage means 'be a component of some manufactured (large scale implied) item'.

@EdwinAshworth That's close to literal, the sugar is moving into the batter.

@Barmar: The example is. 'Flour, eggs, butter and sugar go into most cakes' obviously = 'Flour, eggs, butter and sugar go into making most cakes'. I'd have added an answer if I'd found a dictionary definition that was spot on. CD has 'If time, money, or effort goes into a product or activity, it is used when producing or doing it:
A considerable amount of time and effort has gone into this exhibition.'

... Longman arguably loosely licenses 'Much of the steel produced in the U.S. goes into manufacturing automobiles.' with 'to be spent or used to get, make, or do something', but adds the domain restrictions 'time, money, effort'. It's a pity 'raw/starting materials' isn't included.

I’m not sure I get your point, @EdwinAshworth. Certainly we don’t bow down to Longman’s licensure—or more to the point, their withholding of it—with regard to a usage that is (whatever Longman may say) empirically quite common and unexceptionable.

Who are 'we'? ELU vastly prefers answers that are supported by accepted authorities. Even the late and sadly missed John Lawler used to link to articles etc. Usually, for idiomaticity (and this drives acceptability) of words and senses, that's dictionaries. Answers that aren't so supported often come across as (and may be) mere opinion. // This is certainly one case where most if not all dictionaries miss a well-established usage.

All I’m saying, @EdwinAshworth, is that we here at EL&U generally try to avoid prescriptivism. And as you write, “This is certainly … a well-established usage.”

I was trying to find dictionary support for the usage. I'd expect an answer to show the results of such research, even if corroboration proved not to be easily available.

Ok, @EdwinAshworth, now I understand. And I absolutely agree that answers backed with strong sourcing are much to be preferred over those (like mine here) that don’t include such backing.

@EdwinAshworth, our exchange motivated me to find a good citation of the usage, and ironically I found one nearly identical to the one I had made up. My answer has been edited accordingly.
